# Excel 2016 Linked Workbooks Slow to update from SharePoint Online (2007 is fine)

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online

We have several workbooks in the business that act as a summary area, pulling in data directly (='a given cell in said linked workbooks') from lots of other workbooks, let's say 100 workbooks.

Recently we moved all of our files to SharePoint Online (2013), now when users of Excel 2016 (and 2013 for that matter) open one of these summary style workbooks and click update, it takes at least 10 minutes to update everything. Meanwhile, we have one user still on Excel 2007, her summary workbooks update very quickly, more like 1 minute for the same workbook.

Task manager shows that the network activity during the link updates on 2016 is stop-starting with a second or so of inactivity between high bursts of data, meanwhile 2007 just opens the flood gates with constant activity.

This translates in Fiddler 4 also. Updating the linked workbooks with Excel 2016 gives the following activity:

Tunnel to SharePoint site
The actual file
Tunnel to SharePoint Site
A call to CellStorage.svc
Another tunnel
Another CellStorage Call
(Occassionaly there are calls to nexus officeapps live too)

Comparing this to Excel 2007, there is nothing but direct file activity, no tunnels, no cellstorage, and much larger bodies.

It would appear this behaviour is the difference, is that correct and is there any way to stop this behaviour in Excel 2013/16?

Thanks in advance!